# Select entries bases on second column criteria

Tags: mysql

I have this cross_reference table,

```
post_id | cat_id
-----------------
3          11
-----------------
3          2
-----------------
4          5
-----------------
4          6
-----------------
4          2
-----------------
5          8
-----------------
5          13
```

The problem is that this query does not return anything....

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM posts_categories WHERE cat_id = 11 AND cat_id = 2
```

I expect it to return '3'...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually `OR`, not `AND`. Or better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM posts_categories WHERE cat_id IN (11,2);
```

Though I'd expect it to return 3 and 4.

**UPDATE**: (based on the comment)

```
SELECT post_id
FROM post_categories WHERE cat_id IN (2,12)
GROUP BY post_id HAVING count(*)=2;
```

Comment: I want to select all posts that are in both 11 AND 2 categories. I don't want to return posts that are in 11 but not in 2 and in 2 but not in 11

Comment: ah, You should've been clear on that. Lemme update the answer.

Comment: OK, now I need to understand what the HAVING count(*)=2 does... :)

Comment: It makes sure that the post_id has two entries associated with it that satisfy the `IN (2,12)` condition. Of course, I assumed, that post_id,cat_id is a unique key. Otherwise you'd probably want `count(DISTINCT cat_id)`.

Comment: But what if I have more than two in the IN()? I someone wants to find all posts that are in 3 categories or more?

Comment: Then you adjust `HAVING` condition accordingly.

Comment: Oh so I write something like this? count(*)=$x;

Comment: Well, the `$x` part depends on what you're using to access mysql, but generally yes, something like that.